# Page up in Mac OS X and in Ubuntu under Virtualbox in Mac OS X?

Tags: key-bindings, osx, ubuntu

What are the keystrokes for page up

- In Mac OS X,
- In Ubuntu installed in Virtualbox in Mac OS X?

both alt-V and command-V don't perform page-up.

I am running emacs in a terminal emulator.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you in a terminal on the virtual machine, or in a graphical version of Emacs on the virtual machine?  And, have you checked the virtual machine pre-configured keyboard shortcuts (Preferences) -- for example, Parallels has options to respect or disregard system keyboard shortcuts, a special keyboard shortcut to display the virtual machine if it his hidden, keyboard shortcuts that only affect the virtual machine.  In short, there are just too many variables in the question (as it stands now) for anyone to properly answer it -- unless a wild guess just happens to be correct.  See also `C-h k`

Comment: thanks. just updated with your first question. Am looking into the second one, and not sure about it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnome terminal intercepts alt-V to pull down the menu for "View".
This is completely an issue within emacs running inside Gnome Terminal.

The solution is to uncheck "enable the menu access keys" in gnome terminal's shortcut keys' settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask emacs this question directly. Use `C-h f scroll-up-command RET` to open the help for this function; it'll say also what key or keys it's bound to. It's probably `C-v` and `<next>` (useful should you have a keyboard with a 'next' key).

Comment: it says Ctrl-V, which is actually scroll down one page/screen.

Comment: Oh, the function names are somewhat confusing here. `scroll-up-command` scrolls the document up, allowing you to read further down into the file. This means that you actually want `scroll-down-command`.